# SQLite to ExpandableLIstView using custom adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, expandablelistview

I want to show expandable listview in my app. I have stored data in sqlite in tw table Main_Categories and Sub_Categories. Main_categories has 3 columns (Id, Name, Remote_id) and Sub_categoris has 4 columns (Id, Name, Remote_id, Parent_category_id). Please Help me. How can i set this data to ExpandableListView.

For example:

Main_Categories tabel:

```
ID | Name    | Remote_id
 1 | Drinks  | 335
 2 | Bags    | 340
```

Sub _Categories table

```
ID | Name      | Remote_id | Parent_categories_id
1  | pepsi     | 336       | 335
2  | Fenta     | 338       | 335
3  | Coke      | 339       | 335
4  | paperbags | 341       | 340
5  | Plasticbag| 342       | 340
```

So, I want to show my ExpandableListView Like this :

```
Drinks
 - pepsi
 - Fenta
 - Coke
Bags
 - paperbags
 - plasticbag
```

P.S :I have almost 20+ Main categories and 50+ sub categories.

Comment: Ok, do that. I won't stop you.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi haha really most suitable answer for the post !!

Comment: I want to know the solution @HrundiV.Bakshi

Comment: Then find a tutorial. This site is not a learning center.

Comment: @HrundiV.Bakshi I have tried but couldent find anything meaningful. Thats why i asked here. Can you please help me.

Comment: Google keywords: `android expandablelistview database`